# Is it possible to get difference of count of two different activities in google analytics?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I'm tracking two different events into `GoogleAnalytics` from my iOS app. I want to get the difference between these two events.

> difference = sum of(Event A) - sum of (Event B).

Please guide me through the proper solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. You would have to export the data (e.g via the API, or Google Apps Script, or simply using the export to spreadsheet function in GA) and calculate the difference e.g with a spreadsheet formula.

The closest you will get in the interface is via segmentation (something like "show uniqe events for EventA for users that do not also have EventB"). But as a simple number in the reports, no. GA does not do user defined calculations in the interface.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused about analytics.